# jasperreports cannot compile with datetime functions - symbol not found

Tags: groovy, compilation, jasper-reports

Jasperreports 6.5.1.  In Studio I can run a report that has a textExpression of "TODAY()".  In my web server app though, with the jasperreports jar embedded, I get this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol\r\n                value = TODAY( );
```

I have the DateTimeFunctions imported, and the function is on the java classpath, but I guess not for the compiler.  This is what I have for code, with an attempt to import the required functions statically:

```
def c = new DateTimeFunctions()
def x = c.TODAY()

JRXmlLoader loader = new JRXmlLoader(new SimpleJasperReportsContext(), new Digester())
JasperDesign designFile = loader.load(sourceFilePath)

// Ensure that custom functions are available when compiling reports.
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.TextFunctions.*")
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.MathFunctions.*")
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.LogicalFunctions.*")
designFile.addImport("static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.DateTimeFunctions.*")

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(designFile)
```

I can compile other jrxml files but the one that has TODAY() in it throws the exception.  I suspect this is the case for all the static imports but I can't even get beyond the TODAY() problem.  Note that the datetime jar is there in the java classpath because I can call TODAY() as a test.

The source file is groovy; not sure whether that messes with the static imports, or what the problem is.  Any help?

Thanks for Alex K's response confirming that nothing mysterious should be going on.  I don't think I need groovy-all since I'm not scripting in groovy, it's just that the source file is in groovy.  I looked at the generated java code for the JasperCompileManager and see

```
import static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.DateTimeFunctions.*;
```

and in the evaluate() method I see

```
case 9 : 
{
    value = TODAY( ); //$JR_EXPR_ID=9$
    break;
}
```

However, still the TODAY() method cannot be found.  I will rewrite the groovy file as a java file to see if groovy is messing things up.  For instance, maybe the method name in all caps is a problem.  Or the compiler version - running under 1.8.  Anyway, grasping at straws, but will try to stay afloat.

=====================

Ok, I created a java test file to see why I couldn't resolve "TODAY()".  Here it is, using a static import as generated in the java code from the jrxml file:

```
import java.util.Date;
import static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.DateTimeFunctions.*;

class Test {
  Date dtest() {
    return TODAY();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    Date d = t.dtest();
    System.out.println(d);
  }
}
```

And compiling it gives:

```
javac -cp ./jasperreports-6.5.1.jar;./jasperreports-functions-6.5.1.jar Test.java
Test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
            return TODAY();
                   ^
symbol:   method TODAY()
location: class Test
1 error
```

Ok, my java skills aren't the best, so what am I missing here?  I am compiling with java version "1.8.0_171".

The only way I can make this work is if the statically imported method is declared "public static".  That is,

```
public static Date TODAY() { ...
```

but that is not what is in the DateTimeFunctions.java source.

=========================

So, if I read the 6.6.0 documentation here:  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/index.html, the sample DateTimeFunctions are all declared static, which seems to me to be correct.  So, have I downloaded bogus functions jars for 6.5.1, and 6.6.0, and are the "real" ones somewhere yet-to-be-discovered?

Comment: You confused me :) Do you have trouble with jrxml or with groovy code? `For instance, maybe the method name in all caps is a problem` - The name of method in uppercase. What version of JR are you using? Your case is unclear

Comment: Not a problem with jrxml, which works fine in Studio and Reports Server, but fails when I embed the jar into a groovy file (Grails plugin). It fails to resolve the TODAY function.  Yet the import is there in the java classpath.  And no, I don't believe it's because the method name is all caps.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add import in case using *groovy* language at template and having *org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all* and *net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-functions* libraries at classpath.

This *jrxml* working fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TODAY using" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" language="groovy">
    <title>
        <band height="60">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[TODAY()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- some dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The same is working for default *java* language.

---

The static imports is also working at *JasperReports*.

The example of using some method from *Guava* library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Static import" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
    <import value="static com.google.common.base.Strings.repeat"/>
    <title>
        <band height="60">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="200" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[repeat("a", 3)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The generated result will be:

[image: PDF output]